# Canvas map with looping background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am working on Browser game, and I wanted to make map where you can move around, fight with mobs, buy some stuff, but only map. Everything else will be in different pages.

So I made map with multiple images which are in loop.
It reads value world, x and y from database. I have made it work with ajax so the page doesnt refresh every time you move, but I wanted to make this map using Canvas.

```
$ystart = $y - 2;
$ymax = $y + 2;
$xstart = $x - 3;
$xmax = $x + 3;
for($y=$ystart;$y<=$ymax;$y++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($x=$xstart;$x<=$xmax;$x++){


       // echo "<td><img src=images/map/day/".$x."_".$y.".jpg width=100 height=100 border=0></td>\n";
        if($x==$posx and $y==$posy){
            echo "<td background=images/map/world_".$world."/".$y."_".$x.".jpg><img src=images/char.png width=100 height=100 border=0></td>";
        } else{
            echo "<td><img src=images/map/world_".$world."/".$y."_".$x.".jpg width=100 height=100 border=0></td>";
        }

    }
    echo "</tr>";
}?>
```

I have done this so far

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startGame()">
  <script>
    var myGamePiece;
    var myUpBtn;
    var myDownBtn;
    var myLeftBtn;
    var myRightBtn;

    function startGame() {
      myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
      myUpBtn = new component(30, 30, "blue", 50, 10);
      myDownBtn = new component(30, 30, "blue", 50, 70);
      myLeftBtn = new component(30, 30, "blue", 20, 40);
      myRightBtn = new component(30, 30, "blue", 80, 40);
      myGameArea.start();

    }


    var myGameArea = {

      canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),

      start: function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);


        window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
          myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
          myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
        })
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
          myGameArea.x = false;
          myGameArea.y = false;
        })
        window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
          myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
          myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
        })
        window.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
          myGameArea.x = false;
          myGameArea.y = false;
        })
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
          myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
          myGameArea.key = false;
        })
      },
      clear: function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.speedX = 0;
      this.speedY = 0;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      }
      this.clicked = function() {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var clicked = true;
        if ((mybottom < myGameArea.y) || (mytop > myGameArea.y) || (myright < myGameArea.x) || (myleft > myGameArea.x)) {
          clicked = false;
        }
        return clicked;
      }
      this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
      }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
      myGameArea.clear();
      myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
      myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
      if (myGameArea.x && myGameArea.y) {
        if (myUpBtn.clicked()) {
          myGamePiece.y -= 1;
        }
        if (myDownBtn.clicked()) {
          myGamePiece.y += 1;
        }
        if (myLeftBtn.clicked()) {
          myGamePiece.x += -1;
        }
        if (myRightBtn.clicked()) {
          myGamePiece.x += 1;
        }
      }
      myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
      myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
      if (myGameArea.key && (myGameArea.key == 37 || myGameArea.key == 65)) {
        myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
      }
      if (myGameArea.key && (myGameArea.key == 39 || myGameArea.key == 68)) {
        myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
      }
      if (myGameArea.key && (myGameArea.key == 38 || myGameArea.key == 87)) {
        myGamePiece.speedY = -1;
      }
      if (myGameArea.key && (myGameArea.key == 40 || myGameArea.key == 83)) {
        myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
      }
      myGamePiece.newPos();
      myUpBtn.update();
      myDownBtn.update();
      myLeftBtn.update();
      myRightBtn.update();
      myGamePiece.update();
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

But I can't figure out how to make this background loop in canvas based on x and y position and how to make it change when you move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to learn about canvas myself, so I've been browsing through these questions. I thought yours would be a fun exercise to try.

Basically, I'm creating an object, and moving it at each iteration. I will constantly check the x position of my object. And depending on its value, I can change the background image.

Try this and see for yourself. Try moving your right arrow key and then left arrow key. You will notice the background image changes.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-26.jpg')";


function hero(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.moveLeft = function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        this.x -= 5;
        drawHero(this.x, this.y);
    };
    this.moveRight = function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        this.x += 5;
        drawHero(this.x, this.y);
    };
    this.moveUp = function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        this.y -= 5;
        drawHero(this.x, this.y);
    }
    this.moveDown = function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        this.y += 5;
        drawHero(this.x, this.y);
    }
}

function drawHero(x,y) {
 ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
}

var hero1 = new hero(40, 40);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(40, 40, 10, 10);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
 if (event.keyCode == 38) {
     hero1.moveUp();
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 37) {
     hero1.moveLeft();
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
     hero1.moveRight();
    }
    else {
     hero1.moveDown();
    }
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (hero1.x <= 100) {
        canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/background-wallpapers-26.jpg')";
    }
    else if (hero1.x > 100 && hero1.x <= 200) {
        canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRi2F1v1PXpOEYScFCbvmsV-74C573z8tFBvIPXwDO8d1KImpJ09Q')";
    }
    else {
        canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSOSNoN1aLzWvpwrENvqPb4tKgzfeeqlMsUeC0fjdGABXXLdLIo')";
    }
},50);
```

```css
#my-canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```